# Oracle SOA / Message expires even when TTL is set to 0

Tags: oracle, jms, soa, bpel

I have a Oracle BPEL service that posts message on a Uniform Distributed Queue.
I have set JMS Adapter's TimeToLive property value as 0. 
I have also ensured that the queue's Time-to-Live Override is -1 on admin console.

Sometimes it happens that message gets expired after 7-8 mins queue receives it.
Although it doesn't happen everytime, I am wondering if there is any other setting I should be looking into.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TIA